# How can I find peaks in an EKG when the polarity may be inverted?

Tags: matlab, ecg

I am working on finding the peaks in EKGs using Matlab. I have a couple of hundred of recordings.  The problem is that some of them have their peaks inverted (so they are negative.) The goal is to be able to find the peaks without having to visually inspect the files to determine if they are reversed or not. I want to find a way to either:

1. Determine if the EKG is inverted. If it is inverted I can use the negative value of the EKG and then find peaks
2. Find a way to determine peaks regardless if they are positive or negative.

I have already tried to use the 'skewness' to determine if the peaks are positive or negative but I still get positive values in ECGs that I know are inverted so it does not work well for my data. I cannot upload the data but here is a program that might help:

```
fs=1000;
t=[0:1/fs:3000];
x=zeros(length(t),1);
for i=1:5
x=x+i*sin(2*pi*2*i*t');
end
plot(t,x)
[peak loc]=findpeaks(x,'MinPeakProminence',12);
hold on
plot(t(loc), x(loc),'*r')
xlim([0 20])
hold off
```

Sample image from the real data:

[image: sample]

Comment: It would help if you post some data files or pictures from the data. Without seeing the data it's impossible to tell what algorithm might work here or not

Comment: i do not know how to upload a data file, but I have added a picture from one of the files with inversed ECG.

Comment: That seems easy enough: look for the maximum and the minimum of the file. If the absolute value of the minimum is bigger: flip it.

Comment: Why not simply find the peaks of the absolute value of the waveform?

Comment: if you cant take the absolute value you could find the min and the max and determine which one of those is larger in magnitude and then try to find all the peaks based off a percentage of the max magnitude. for example max is -10 find all points within 80% of that -8 to -10.